# iOS - The best way to draw thousands of symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best way to display thousands or even more dynamic symbols (like Matrix's rain) ? 
I tried to do that in drawRect method by

```
    for (NSString *symbol in self.symbols) {
        [symbol drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(posX, posY) 
             withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : self.font, 
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color}];
    }
```

But much smaller the font, so much more laggy it becomes.
e.g. when font pointSize is 10, then CPU percentage is 98%.

So what is the best way to show a lot of symbols and redraw them every milliseconds from performance side ?

Answer (score 1):

For graphics intensive processes like this you'll need to use [OpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/introduction/introduction.html) or possibly [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: SpriteKit? How? 
Using SKLabel O_o ?